# How can I display a yes/no message box to the user in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I display a yes/no message box to the user on the client-side in Javascript?

I don’t want to display “OK” and “Cancel” to the user, which is the default behavior of the `confirm` function in Javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a easy to use plugin to do it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't amend the Ok/Cancel of the default confirm box, but you can use a 3rd party library (such as jQuery/jQuery UI) which will give you what you need: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this jquery plugin http://www.84bytes.com/2008/06/02/jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has modal confirmation boxes

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

I just posted in my blog an easy to use Yes/No message box that you can easily modify to fit your project.

Example:

```
SmallJS.message.modal('Do you want to click yes?', {
                buttons: {
                    ok: 'Yes',
                    cancel:'No'
                },
                onOK: function () {
                    SmallJS.message.show('Yes sir!', { animate:false});
                }
            })
```

You can see the source code at: http://www.waltersoto.com/javascript/javascript-yes-no-message-box